# Photoshop - Select & Mask - keyboard shortcut

Tags: photoshop, keyboard-shortcuts

What are the keyboard shortcuts available when in Select and Mask? (PS 2020)

I'm specifically looking for the keyboard shortcut to change from + to - while in Select and Mask
(see image attached)

[image: Select and Mask]

Answer (score 1):

Same as anything else +/- based in Photoshop, if + is default, then hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   or Win  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  to swap to —

For any selection method, Lasso, Marquee etc., if there's no default as there is in Select and Mask then  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  will add,  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  will subtract.

Comment: While this is an answer it is only a temporary solution. One has to continue to hold the key (Opt or Alt) down to use this. I was looking for a one time shortcut that would toggle this. As an example just like the use of 'X' to swap foreground and background colors.